# How to build latex to .doc file

Tags: latex-to-word

I have an latex project, I want to build to .doc file, but current latex compile only support build to pdf

Comment: pandoc is a choice for converting tex to word.

Comment: There are many ways (e.g., `TeX4ht, Chikri, GrindEq`, etc.), but after conversion, you need to do work with the converted Word file, No converter provides exact output as same as `TeX` output

Comment: You can use odt format, try the command line ` make4ht -f odt filename.tex` and later with libre office you can convrt to .doc file